# Android: Gson serialization is missing one specific field

Tags: android, serialization, gson

This is the class

```
class TransactionDetails {

    @SerializedName("item")
    private String item;
    @SerializedName("itemPrice")
    private double itemPrice;
    @SerializedName("commissions")
    private double commissions;
    @SerializedName("itemCount")
    private double itemCount;
    @SerializedName("when")
    private long when;
    @SerializedName("tax")
    private double tax;

    TransactionDetails(String item, double itemPrice, double commissions, double itemCount, long when, double tax) {
        this.item = item;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.commissions = commissions;
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
        this.when = when;
        this.tax = tax;
    }

    String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    double getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    double getCommissions() {
        return commissions;
    }

    double getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    long getWhen() {
        return when;
    }

    double getTotalPrice() {
        return itemCount * itemPrice;
    }

    String getWhenStr() {
        return Utils.getInstance().getDateStr(when);
    }

    double getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

}
```

double getTax() is the only method I don't use in my code because I have no use for it in my app, so I see "method getTax() is never used" though I'm not sure it is related

This is the instance

```
ArrayList<TransactionDetails> transactionDetailsFull = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the failing code

```
new Gson().toJson(Utils.getInstance().transactionDetailsFull);
```

For some reason, the above code serializing all the fields of the class except for tax. That happens ONLY when in release mode:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

In debug mode, it works. Notice that I did @SerializedName so I don't understand what am I missing and what is causing only tax not to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Are you add Gson and your class(TransactionDetails) in proguard file?
If no.
Try to change proguard file like this:

```
# Add the gson class
-keep public class com.google.gson

# Add any classes the interact with gson
-keep class yourpackage.TransactionDetails { *; }
```

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, the problem might be the opposite, meaning something extra in the proguard file. In the past I had a problem with serializing and I played with the proguard file but it didn't help. Only adding @serializedName made it work. Maybe I did something then that is affecting this problem now.

Comment: Can you post your json?

Comment: I don't have anything in proguard that is related to "transaction" or "tax". the json is obvious: debug: [{"commissions":5.0,"itemPrice":30.55,"itemCount":30.0,"item":"bottle","tax":15.0,"when":17094}]. release: [{"commissions":5.0,"itemPrice":30.55,"itemCount":30.0,"item":"bottle", "when":17094}]. Just the tax is missing.

Comment: I test release version without:  -keep public class com.google.gson and -keep class yourpackage.TransactionDetails { *; }  then the result is an empty json like this: { }.   but when i add these lines in proguard-rules.pro the result is json with all attributs and tax also.

Comment: In the past I had a problem with serializing the class with minify true and adding those lines to proguard didn't help. Only adding @serializedName made it work. Same now. adding  -keep public class com.google.gson and -keep class mypackage.TransactionDetails { *; } to proguard-android-optimize.txt didn't add tax to the serialization. There must be a silly something causing all this.

Comment: I did add the tax property later but I don't understand why it "remembers" the old structure when minifying and shrinking...

Comment: well, apparently this part was wrong: double getTax() is the only method I don't use in my code because I have no use for it in my app, so I see "method getTax() is never used" though I'm not sure it is related. I added a reference in my code to getTax() and now Gson serializing it....

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently this part was wrong: double getTax() is the only method I don't use in my code because I have no use for it in my app, so I see "method getTax() is never used" though I'm not sure it is related. I added a reference in my code to getTax() and now Gson serializing it...

Maybe a bug or maybe something I don't understand with how serializing works...